# Equivalent CryptoJS SHA512 hash of content Hex encoded for python?

Tags: javascript, python, cryptojs, hashlib

I am trying to make an authenticated API call. Documentation example in JS states that contentHash header has to be populated with:

```
content = {currencySymbol:symbol};
var contentHash = CryptoJS.SHA512(JSON.stringify(content)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
```

I am writing my request in Python and I keep getting INVALID_CONTENT_HASH. This is what I have so far:

```
content = {"currencySymbol":"BTC"}
contentHash = hashlib.sha512(json.dumps(content, separators=(',',':')).encode('latin1')).hexdigest()
```

Hash: 18aa13a42b5efe3c45b37050626f23fcc4f3b4acf5e479f2f50212722cdcd80baa0ba6ddf8dcbd0f1b88008aaf9ec33874e4be9ab6ec2dece611c2dbdca87560

Expected Hash: e6e0b5e9941269e61fb41bd4f6a0dc5be0da1c011087a057ff88fe3de98f41c6681983dd14662c88b6293663d942c93511c3fd7f9cc5250e686b16de53a18f57

I don't know what is wrong with my request. Please advice.

Comment: Can you link the API you are using?

Comment: Where did you get that "Expected Hash"? I tried running the original JS and found that the first hash ("Hash") was what came out. Can you check to see if this matches what you expected? https://runkit.com/elliotaplant/5f3eb7e859b2e600139a8b52

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `json.dumps` applies some minor pretty-printing by default but `JSON.stringify` does not.

Try this:

```
content = {'currencySymbol':'BTC'}
contentHash = hashlib.sha512(json.dumps(content, separators=(',',':')).encode('latin1')).hexdigest()
```

By adding the `separators=(',',':')` to `json.dumps`, it will remove the extra whitespace that is added by default

[documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for `json.dumps`

Comment: Thank you for you solution but I still get the same hash.

Comment: Can you link the api you are using?

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry I tried fiddling with it for 15 minutes or so and couldn't figure it out.  Their API isn't the best :/

Comment: You could try re-asking the question and making it a question about the bittrex API specificially.  Someone else might know how to set it up.